# unable to list the oracle table names with sqoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to connect to oracle db and list the names of the tables with sqoop like this:

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<db server>:1521:DB_Name--
```

username hdp --password hadoop

I dont get any errors back. There are bunch of tables on the database server but cannot get it listed with sqoop. Any ideas what I am missing? I temporarily gave dba rights to the hdp user, still cannot get the list of tables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should add space before double dash

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<db server>:1521:DB_Name --username hdp --password hadoop
```

And from what I saw in to the documentation the format should be something like:

```
sqoop --connect jdbc:oracle//<db server>:1521/DB_Name --username hdp --password hadoop --list-tables
```

If you only need the list of the tables in oracle why do not use `sqlplus`?

Comment: also space before `--username`